# If you get a significant $p$-value from an ANOVA, how can you tell which groups are different?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I'm performing an experiment and have gotten a $p$-value that is supposedly significant with a value of $0.00001$. Now my question is, how can I tell which groups are different from one another?

Comment: Have you examined the group means?  You might also want to search this site for [HSD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=HSD) to get some ideas.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to generalize this question to: "If you get a significant $p$-value from an ANOVA, how can you tell which groups are different?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have some anova model in R like the following:

`ANOVA <- aov(y ~ x)`

This model estimates the means of each of $k$ categories in `x` and an omnibus test can be performed to test whether there is significant deviation from all means being equal:

$\text{H}_0: \mu_1=\mu_2=\dots=\mu_k$

You can produce a summary in R, which will report the $p$-value for this omnibus test (`summary(ANOVA)`). **This is the $p $-value you obtained in your question**. There is some difference among means, you don't know where.

**Post hoc**
To find out *which* means differ from which, you will need to perform a post hoc analysis - an analysis after the initial ANOVA. This is usually Tukey's honest significant difference test (HSD). To do this in R, simply run:

`post.hoc <- TukeyHSD(ANOVA)`

You can then print it to see the estimated differences, ranges of the confidence intervals and $p$-values. These $p$-values are already corrected for multiple testing, so you don't need to worry about that (hence `p adj` in the output):

`print(post.hoc)`

You can also plot the confidence intervals, although the labels usually don't fit in the plot, so you may want to adjust the graphical parameters, for example:

`par(mar = c(5, 7, 4, 3)+0.1) # bottom, left, top, right`
`plot(post.hoc, las = 1)`
`par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 3)+0.1) # back to default`

Confidence intervals which do not include zero are significant in this case.